# Is there a MIME type that tells browsers "don't try to detect the type, just display as text"?

Tags: http, mime-types

While testing some HTTP server code, I noticed something odd: if I return `Content-Type: text/plain`, browsers will *not* render the content as plain text. Instead, they seem to assume that the server must be misconfigured, and they try to *detect* the content type instead.

For example, if I return the contents of a PNG file, but with `Content-Type: text/plain`:

- FireFox and IE9 both look at the extension on the URL. If it ends in `.png`, they display it as an image. If not (e.g. if I return the same content from a URL that ends in `.xyz`), they prompt me to save the file.
- Chrome and Opera both look at the file's contents, detect that it's a PNG, and display it as an image.

Granted, it wouldn't make sense to return a PNG as `text/plain` in production; but if I'm testing whether my server is returning the correct `Content-Type`, the browsers' second-guessing behavior gets in the way. Plus it's just kinda goofy, which gets me curious about whether there's a way to work around it.

Is there a way -- with a different `Content-Type`, or an additional HTTP header, or whatever -- that I can tell the browser, "Show this as text, no really, I actually know what I'm doing"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-websec-mime-sniff-03#section-4 for context.

In some UAs, adding as custom parameter such as

text/plain; imeanit=yes

might help.

Some IE versions support

X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff

see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg622941%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: `X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff` works on Chrome (v14) and IE (v9). `Content-Type: text/plain; imeanit=yes` works on FireFox (v7). The combination gets everything but Opera, but since there seems to be no agreement on which spec to follow or how to follow it, it looks like that's as close to an answer as I'm going to get. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What kind of data are you *actually* returning?  Are you certain it's relying on the URL, or is the server ignoring your request to change the content type?  Have you examined the headers that the browser sees?  If you really are sending a png as "text", than I think the browsers are doing the right thing by detecting the actual data type since you're likely causing exceptions in their text rendering routines.

Comment: Edited to explain why I'm certain it's relying on the URL. The actual content is the raw bytes from a PNG file. Yes, I've examined the headers (using `curl --head`).

Comment: Well, I can't tell you authoritatively, but I suspect the answer is that you cannot *require* the browser to do anything.  Additionally, if you do find a work around for a specific browser, it probably won't work for all of them.